# Can i config many HMaster of HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

as i know that HBase runs with ZooKeeper, it has 2 HMaster is active and inactive, So can i config many HMaster? Just like Hadoop have many namenode, can HBase have many HMaster? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HBase can have Backup Masters. Only one Master will be active at any time, but if it fails, one of the Backup Masters will become Master.

You specify Backup Masters in the `/HBase/conf/backup-masters` file Just list host name entries one per line, like you do for Region Servers.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so i can have as much as Backup Masters if i want right. Will all of them auto save data from Master ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'auto save data', but yes you can enter one host name per line.

Comment: hmmm i mean, like sub-namenode it will update fig from namenode and when namenode fail, it can coninues without any problem. Will HMaster act like that?

Comment: Yes, when main Master fails, one of the backup masters will take over and you don't have to do anything. The information on regions/etc. should remain known among the zookeeper and the meta table, so the transition should be smooth. At least that's been my experience with this.

Comment: oh thank you Sir. bigdata doc seem hard to find in the internet. I just know  when HBase has problem, it will repair itself :((